DacDeploy ScriptDatabaseOptions option is ignored during deployment
I have written a tool to update multiple databases as part of our DEVOPS CI/CD pipeline. This tool works without issue.
We are migrating host platforms for our SaaS product, and as part of this, I want to change the recovery mode of our MS SQL databases. At the same time, I don't want to alter the recovery mode in the old platform.
The recovery mode in the DACPAC files is set to SIMPLE. On the new target platform, I want it to be FULL.
As far as I can see, I should be able to do this by setting:

ScriptDatabaseOptions = false

This is ignored during deployment. If I set the target database to FULL recovery mode in Management Studio, following the deployment of the DACPAC with ScriptDatabaseOptions = false, the recovery mode reverts to SIMPLE.
I know I could bust open the DACPAC and alter the RecoveryMode property as part of the DEVOPS pipeline, but this would be a pain as we have many pipelines and stages.
How can I force the deployment to ignore the recovery mode correctly?
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac;

public void ProcessDacpac(string dacpacFile)
{
    foreach (var sqlConnectionString in sqlConnectionStrings)
    {
        Logger.LogToFile($"Start DacPackage Deploy for: {sqlConnectionString.Key}",Logger.LogCondition.Verbose);

        //check if server and database is online
        Logger.LogToFile($"Testing Connection For: {sqlConnectionString.Key}",Logger.LogCondition.Verbose);

        if (!IsServerAndDatabaseOnline(sqlConnectionString.Value))
        {
            Logger.LogToFile($"Connection Failed: {sqlConnectionString.Key}", Logger.LogCondition.Critical);
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            Logger.LogToFile($"Testing Connection For: {sqlConnectionString.Key} Success", Logger.LogCondition.Verbose);
        }

        var services = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices(sqlConnectionString.Value);
        services.Message += (object sender, Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacMessageEventArgs eventArgs) => Logger.LogToFile(eventArgs.Message.Message, Logger.LogCondition.Verbose);

        var dacpac = DacPackage.Load(dacpacFile);
        
        //publish options
        var dacDeployOptions = new DacDeployOptions()
        {
            ScriptDatabaseOptions = false, // <------- this is ignored!
            BlockOnPossibleDataLoss = false, //All these other options are respected. 
            IgnoreColumnOrder = true,
            AllowIncompatiblePlatform = true,
            ExcludeObjectTypes = new ObjectType[] { ObjectType.Users, ObjectType.RoleMembership, ObjectType.Permissions, ObjectType.Logins },
            TreatVerificationErrorsAsWarnings = true
        };

        try
        {
            services.Deploy(dacpac, sqlConnectionString.Key, true, dacDeployOptions);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogToFile(ex.Message, ex, Logger.LogCondition.Critical);
            throw;
        }

        Logger.LogToFile($"END DacPackage Deploy for: {sqlConnectionString.Key}", Logger.LogCondition.Verbose);
    }
}


I upgraded Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx to version 162.4.92, which resolved the issue. I was previously on version 162.3.566.1.
I can only assume there was a bug in the previous version.
